# Inserting data into mySQL database through PHP is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to figure out how to insert data into mySQL database for a long time. When I try to insert data, it returns "no database selected". I'm not too sure what's wrong with the code, could someone check it out?

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$database= "learnsc2_ts";
$username = "learnsc2_admin";
$password = "Ts@123";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
else {
     echo "Connection successful";
}
$query = "INSERT INTO users(fname, lname) VALUES ('Owen', 
'Feng')";
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
   echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
   echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);?>
```

Comment: Your current problem aside, what are `{fname}` and `{lname}` in your insert query supposed to be doing?

Comment: fname and lname are the places where the values "Owen" and "Feng" are supposed to go.

Comment: If your column is `fname` it should be just `fname` if it has the curlies encapsulate in backticks. Same for `lname`. The `mysqli_error($conn)` doesnt give anything back? You also are executing the query twice.

Comment: Yeah. I just get the error "no database is selected"

Comment: I edited my question. Regardless, I followed Alex's advice and fixed my database info, but it's still returning no database selected

Comment: update question if you have made changes.

Comment: Question's code is updated

Comment: Remove tha single quotes wrapping fname and lname.

Comment: And make sure `learnsc2_ts` database exists to prevent "no database selected" error.

Comment: When I test whether the database is connected in the beginning, it returns that connection is successful, but when I then try to connect it to learnsc2_ts (which is the correct name), it returns no database selected.

Comment: Be sure you are editing the correct file.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? I'm new to coding, sorry.

Comment: You are executing the query twice

Comment: You may be editing a file and executing a different file. Make sure you are doing both on the same file.

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing both on the same file. However, I'm not sure how I'm executing the query twice. Could you please explain?

Comment: It means you have to remove the first `mysqli_query();` statement as only one of it is needed.

Comment: Also your last `else block` has be to closed correctly with a `}` character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your database name is correct.
i tested it in my local, It's work Just fine.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$database= "test";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$query = "INSERT INTO users(fname, lname) VALUES ('Owen', 
'Feng')";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if ($query) {
   echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
   echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

[image: Here Is the Data]

Comment: Yay! I got it to work! It turns out that there was something wrong with the old database that I was using. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add database name

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
```

Comment: I fixed it, but it's still returning "no database selected"

Comment: Still returning "No database selected". However, when I first test whether a connection is established using $conn, it returns Connection successful.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Something was wrong with the old username I was using. After changing to a new username and database, it worked out!